# How to encrypt data with no meta character in result using symmetric-key algorithms in PHP

Tags: php, cryptography

I need a symmetric-key cryptography algorithm which return only Alphabet and Numbers in result without any meta character. Is there anything in PHP?

Comment: You can use bin2hex and hex2bin to convert the binary output of any encryption to ascii hexadecimal string and back.

Comment: @kainaw Post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using encrypt() and decrypt() as your encryption scheme and it spits out binary valued encryption. You can use:

```
$plaintext = "My Super Secret";
$cryptbin = encrypt($plaintext, $mykey);
$crypthex = bin2hex($cryptbin); // This is ascii
// some code and you want to decrypt later...
$cryptbin = hex2bin($crypthex);
$plaintext = decrypt($cryptbin, $mykey);
```